# Json schema property aliasing

Tags: json, validation, alias, jsonschema

The following JSON Schema describes a valid JSON for a lat/lon coordinate:

```
{
    "title": "coordinates",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "longitude": {
        "type": "number",
        "minimum": -180,
            "maximum":180,
            "exclusiveMinimum": false,
            "exclusiveMaximum": false
        },
        "latitude": {
        "type": "number",
        "minimum": -180,
            "maximum":180,
            "exclusiveMinimum": false,
            "exclusiveMaximum": false
        }
    },
    "required": ["longitude", "latitude"],
    "additionalProperties":false
}
```

The `required` setting sets the `latitude` property to be mandatory.

Is there a way to define an alias for the `latitude` key, so that the client can use either `latitude` or `lat` - but not neither and not both?

Answer (score 9):

For "either one or the other, but not both", you need `oneOf`:

```
{
    "oneOf": [
        {"required": ["lat"]},
        {"required": ["latitude"]}
    ]
}
```

All you need then is to have a common definition for the two properties. :)

Answer (score 4):

You can make a property name a pattern (found examples [here](http://json-schema.org/example2.html))

```
{
    "title": "coordinates",
    "type": "object",
    "patternProperties": {
        "/^lat(itude)?$/": {
            "type": "number",
            "minimum": -180,
            "maximum":180,
            "exclusiveMinimum": false,
            "exclusiveMaximum": false
        }
    },
    "additionalProperties":false
}
```

...but this breaks the `required` property (it can't seem to handle patterns). Not a great answer but perhaps helpful. :)